# Restkit Dynamic mapping for random keys

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios6, restkit

I've an issue that "Could not find an object mapping for keyPath:" while mapping the dynamic key.

JSON response is :

```
{
    5471 =     {
        ImageCount = 0;
        InventoryID = "3453dfdsfgt456t3";
        MakeName = aaa;
        ModelName = "a1";
        StockNumber = 5471;
        Year = 2012;
    };
    5516 =     {
        ImageCount = 0;
        InventoryID = "fg456tgev65464b4v";
        MakeName = bbb;
        ModelName = b1;
        StockNumber = 5516;
        Year = 2002;
    };
    5567 =     {
        ImageCount = 0;
        InventoryID = "fdg54646ghy67u65";
        MakeName = ccc;
        ModelName = c1;
        StockNumber = 5567;
        Year = 2008;
    };
}
```

The above keyPath value that 5567,5516,5471 is random value.How could is define key?
My class code is in below:

Class:

```
@interface CategoryPic : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *imageCount_pic;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *inventoryID_pic;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *makeName_pic;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *modelName_pic;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *stockNumber_pic;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *year_pic;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad{

RKObjectMapping* new = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CategoryPic class]];

    [new mapKeyOfNestedDictionaryToAttribute:@"stockid"];
    [new mapKeyPath:@"(stockid).ImageCount" toAttribute:@"imageCount_pic"];
    [new mapKeyPath:@"(stockid).InventoryID" toAttribute:@"inventoryID_pic"];
    [new mapKeyPath:@"(stockid).MakeName" toAttribute:@"makeName_pic"];
    [new mapKeyPath:@"(stockid).ModelName" toAttribute:@"modelName_pic"];
    [new mapKeyPath:@"(stockid).StockNumber" toAttribute:@"stockNumber_pic"];
    [new mapKeyPath:@"(stockid).Year" toAttribute:@"year_pic"];

[[NewSingelton class].objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:new forKeyPath:@"stockid"];

}
```

Comment: Looks like a bogus setup to me. Transform the object to an array of dictionaries with a `randomNumber` field, and make your life easier (and your code readable).

Answer (score 0):

I would transform this into an array and use the random number as one of the fields.

```
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableDictionary *entry = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString *key in jsonObject.allKeys) {
    entry = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:jsonObject[key]];
    [entry addEntriesFromDictionary:@{@"randomNumber" : key}];
    [result addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:entry];
}
```

Or, if your data sample is any indication, just throw this key away as it is the same as StockNumber anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`stockid` should exist as a property on `CategoryPic` so that the value is saved somewhere. If the number always matches `StockNumber` then you can use `stockNumber_pic` and remove that line mapping.